# Yii: How can I attach code to the pagination event for a list view?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I have a few jQuery click/hover events that attach to items in a list view, but when a user clicks to the next page and the results are loaded through ajax the events are no longer valid.

I can use live for some events, but since it is depreciated and inefficient for hover events I'm looking for a way to attach my events to new items when they are loaded... Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for afterAjaxUpdate.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'functionCallBackName()',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify a callback on your $.ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/get/some/data',
     ..., 
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Attach some events to the newly-loaded data or list view...
    }
});
```

If you have any code examples of what you're working with, it would probably help flesh out a decent answer for you - not quite sure if this is what you were looking for or not.

Comment: Yii uses CLinkPager ( http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager ) to handle pagination, I'm just not sure how to interface with it and attach a JS  function to when the page changes